# sshd keypair vs. name+pwd login and authentication credentials

Tags: sshd, windows-server-2022, windows-networking

Windows documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement) makes it clear that logging in with a keypair to `sshd` does not associate user credentials with the session:

```
A remote session opened via key based authentication does not have 
associated user credentials and hence is not capable of outbound 
authentication as the user, this is by design.
```

Is there a way to "secondarily authenticate" with a name+password once logged in via a keypair?